# Sticky footer in asp.net not working

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I am using sticky footer in my page with form tag it's working fine check demo below

http://jsfiddle.net/77v3J/

but when i use `<form>` tag then sticky footer not working please check fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/kn5kF/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your footer class.

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Find the [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/68rmh/).

**EDIT**

If you want to go without position absolute, then add a `height` of `100%` to the `<form>`

For Instance.

`<form method="post" action="abc.aspx" id="form1" style="height:100%;">`

Hope this helps Now.

Comment: without position absolute please :)

Comment: Then add a height of `100%` to the `form`. For Instance `<form method="post" action="abc.aspx" id="form1" style="height:100%;">`. Edited the answer above. - @CSSGuy

Comment: yes this working and i have fine another solution if we add form{display:inline} then it's also working thanks for your all time.

Answer (score 1):

please Add `bottom:0;position:absolute;` in `footer` class

```
 .footer{min-height:48px;
        width:100%; 
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:#ff0000;
        bottom:0;
       position:absolute;
     }
```

Live Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kn5kF/2/

Comment: without position absolute please :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not wrap your entire page in a form tag, all the content of this page does not need submitting. 
Just enclose the data to be returned, I added the form tag into the wrapper and all is good as it should be - your markup was not semantically correct as screen readers think all the content within could be submitted content.

Comment: i have talked about this with my developer and he is saying that this code shown on more than 40 pages we can't change...:(

Comment: Ok appears a front end dev was not part of the build, I guess looking at the answers above a fudge fix is the only way forward if not willing to change the templates - but beware cross browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

Change "body" with your form ID in css file (or scope), it worked for me.

before: `html, body{height: 100%;}`

after: `html, #form1 {height: 100%;}`

i hope it works out for you too.